# Existe-t-il un adjectif décrivant une personne qui a le défaut d'aimer le luxe dans l'excès ?

Tags: vocabulaire, adjectifs, adjectifs-indefinis

Existe-t-il un adjectif décrivant une personne qui a le défaut ou le pêché d'aimer le luxe dans l'excès ? Par exemple une personne qui aime de trop les objets beaux et chers et qui dépense donc au dessus de ses moyens.

Lorsque j'ai recherché la définition de [luxure](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/luxure/48155), le résultat fut tout autre !

Answer (score 3):

Un terme familier qui s'approche de cette défintion est [*flambeur*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/flambeur). Le terme est employé pour désigner tout particulièrement quelqu'un qui dépense de l'argent au jeu de manière ostentatoire, mais il peut être aussi appliqué à d'autres dépenses.

Answer (score 1):

Le plus adapté me semble « opulent ».

On peut aussi dire « Luxuriant » mais il n’évoque pas le côté excès et il est souvent utilisé pour parler d’une végétation débordante.

Answer (score 1):

Moi le terme qui me viens en tête, c'est *prodigue*, mais comme *flambeur*, c'est un terme qui est associé plus à l'acte de dépenser qu'à celui d'accumuler le luxe comme tel. *Bragard* est vieilli et plutôt centré sur l'aspect de vantardise. Des termes comme *criard* ou *kitch* s'intéressent plutôt au manque de goût dont il est fait preuve.

Answer (score -1):

Non locuteur natif du français (mais locuteur natif du grec). Si je n'ai pas bien compris votre question je m'excuse. On peut, je trouve, utiliser le mot **sybarite**.

Voir https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/sybarite ; https://cnrtl.fr/definition/sybarite

> B. − Littér., souvent p. iron. [P. allus. à la réputation des habitants de Sybaris et, en partic., p. réf. à certains aspects de leur façon de vivre] Personne qui aime le luxe, le raffinement en matière de plaisir, qui recherche le confort dans la vie comme dans la pensée ou qui y est habitué. Synon. délicat, sensuel, jouisseur, voluptueux ; anton. ascète.Je compris ce qui chagrinait le marquis dans son bonheur, et je découvris quel était le pli de rose dont soupirait ce sybarite sur sa couche de volupté (Gautier, Fracasse, 1863, p. 195).Brotteaux, en son grenier, lui servit du pain, du fromage et du vin, qu'il avait mis à rafraîchir dans sa gouttière, car il était sybarite (A. France, Dieux ont soif, 1912, p. 159).

**EDIT** (merci @Personne)

Sybarite n'exprime probablement ce que vous désirez. On peut utiliser les adjectifs : **fastueux, luxueux, somptueux, somptuaire** avec le sens désiré.

Comment: Merci pour votre réponse ! Le mot sybarite ne convient pas car il exprime avant tout quelqu'un de « mou, efféminé, corrompu » et aussi qui vit dans la luxure et les plaisirs.

La luxure n'est pas le fait d'aimer à l'excès le luxe, les choses belles et coûteuses !

Comment: Concernant la citation de https://cnrtl.fr/definition/sybarite, je crois que ce n'est pas défini comme un défaut mais plus un trait de caractère. Je pense que beaucoup de personnes pourraient être qualifiées de sybarites car elles aiment le luxe, mais parmi elles, moins aiment le luxe à l'excès ! Merci néanmoins pour ce nouveau mot de vocabulaire assez proche de convenir ;)

Comment: @JKHA : Je ne comprends pas. Désolé vraiment. Voir l'article: https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/sybarite#:~:text=sybarite,pleasures%2C%20call%20her%20a%20sybarite.

Comment: @JKHA Je crois, étant locuteur natif du grec, que sybaritisme/sybarite exprime ce que j'ai compris en lisant votre question.

Comment: Fastueux, luxueux, somptueux

Comment: I think "sybarite" would express someone that loves luxury, whereas I search for an adjectives that expresses someone's fault to love luxury too much. Too much for instance leading him spending way too much money than his salary would allow.

Comment: @JKHA Maintenant, je comprends la nuance. Peut-être il me faut effacer ma réponse.

Comment: @Personne : Merci ; je viens d'éditer ma réponse. J'étais ravi d'avoir trouvé que sybarite existe en français mais j'ai mal compris la nuance de la question:-)!

Comment: @Personne, merci pour votre commentaire ! Je trouve que ces 3 adjectifs relèvent bien du luxe et de la richesse mais aucun ne décrit la personne de façon péjorative. Aucun n'exprime le défaut de trop aimer le luxe. Par exemple somptueux : « Qui est d’une grande richesse, d'une grande magnificence, en parlant des choses mais aussi des gens. » ne répond pas à ma question ! Peut-être tout simplement que le défaut que je recherche n'existe pas en un seul mot !

Comment: https://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/somptuaire

Comment: @Personne L'un des sens de *somptuaire* correspond bien à celui demandé, en particulier dans *consommation somptuaire* que l'on rencontre assez souvent. Je n'ai cependant jamais entendu *somptuaire* pour qualifier directement des personnes.